# Keyboard shifted left in wine

Tags: keyboard, wine

So I have had this strange issue for a while now (As long as I can remember). In most wine applications, my keyboard seems to be shifted one to the right: w is interpreted as e, s as d, a as s, etc.

Maybe my google-fu is just not good enough, but I haven't found anyone online with the same problem, and so, I just have no idea where to even start troubleshooting. The only thing I have noticed is that it seems to have something to do with how applications handle input. For example, osu will handle gameplay related inputs correctly, but not the ones in the menu, so I guess it uses a different input method for low latency gameplay stuff. Similar situation in ltspice, hotkeys are shifted, but text input fields work fine. This problem seems to persist between different wineprefixes.

So, my question is basically... does anyone here have any clue about what is going on here, and maybe how to fix it?

Edit:
I just tried this in sway (wayland), and the problem doesn't seem to be present there. So I guess it is X related? Either way, that isn't really a solution, since, I am not quite ready for wayland yet. But maybe a clue to what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `xmodmap` was causing this (not entirely sure how). I switched to `setxkbmap` instead (apparently `xmodmap` is deprecated).